# How long can I store homemade caramel or butterscotch sauce?

Tags: baking, storage-method, storage-lifetime, caramel

I made a butterscotch sauce for a butterbeer cupcake, but I have about a cup of the sauce left.  How long can I leave it in the fridge since it has heavy cream?  Can I freeze it?  I imagine for most purposes, caramel and butterscotch sauces will have the same storage methods.

Comment: This depends a great deal on the sugar/milk ratio of your sauce. Sugar has preservative properties, so the more sugar it has the longer it lasts. We could make better guesses if we saw your recipe.

Comment: Anthm, it was one 12oz bag of butterscotch chips and 1 cup heavy cream over low heat until the butterscotch chips are melted and mixture is smooth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This similar (also has heavy cream) recipe from epicurious recommends: "Room temperature, up to 3 days; refrigerated, at least 3 months."

http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Caramel-Sauce-105889

...And that conforms to my personal opinion, as well. I would not freeze it.

Answer (score -2):

about a week.  Do not freeze the milk proteins get ruptured when the water crystalizes.  (water expands when frozen).